# Filter some prefixes from option list

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem to remove prefix numbers 100-199 and 200-299
from a list of options on my web page.

The following code is what I've tried:

```html
<select id="category_cabinet" name="category_cabinet" class="form-control" onchange="change_cabinet_search(this.value)">
<option value="0">Please Select</option>
<option value="658">100-PENTADBIRAN</option>
<option value="659">200-PENGURUSAN TANAH &amp; BANGUNAN</option>
<option value="660">300-PENGURUSAN ASET</option>
<option value="661">400-PENGURUSAN KEWANGAN</option>
<option value="662">500-PENGURUSAN SUMBER MANUSIA</option>
<option value="663">100-1-PENTADBIRAN/PERUNDANGAN</option>
<option value="664">100-2-PENTADBIRAN/PERHUBUNGAN AWAM</option>
<option value="679">516-JOHN</option><option value="680">516-1-JOHN/DAVID</option>                      
</select>
<script>
let select = document.querySelector('#category_cabinet').children
for ( let el of select){
  if (el.textContent.match(/^[12]/)) el.remove()
}
</script>
```

The result show me like below the picture:

[image: Output 2]

i.e. some entries are filtered out (for example, the first option 100-PENTADBIRAN is not displayed) but several which match my regex are still included.

How can I show the result like the below the picture:

[image: Output 3]

i.e. remove all options matching the regular expression in the code?

Comment: @Nick Both situation is different

Comment: @ParasRaiyani in what way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is perfectly working, Please Try this:-->**

```
<select id="category_cabinet" name="category_cabinet" class="form-control" onchange="change_cabinet_search(this.value)">
<option value="0">Please Select</option>
<option value="658">100-PENTADBIRAN</option>
<option value="659">200-PENGURUSAN TANAH &amp; BANGUNAN</option>
<option value="660">300-PENGURUSAN ASET</option>
<option value="661">400-PENGURUSAN KEWANGAN</option>
<option value="662">500-PENGURUSAN SUMBER MANUSIA</option>
<option value="663">100-1-PENTADBIRAN/PERUNDANGAN</option>
<option value="664">100-2-PENTADBIRAN/PERHUBUNGAN AWAM</option>
<option value="679">516-JOHN</option><option value="680">516-1-JOHN/DAVID</option>
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#category_cabinet option').each(function(k,v){
             var number=$(v).text().split('-')[0];
            console.log(number,$(v).text());
            if(number >= 100 && number <= 299){
                console.log("remove");
               $(v).remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```